# No maximum match although greedy optional-operator

Tags: java, regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have a concrete pattern:

```
\A
(%\s*!\s*T[eE]X program=(?<programMagic>[^} ]+)\R)?
(\\(documentstyle|documentclass)\s*(\[[^]]*\])?\s*\{(?<docClass>[^} ]+)\})?
```

and i want to match the following string

```
% !TEX program=lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
```

I do matching with multiline flag.

As one can see it is about matching the beginning of a latex root file
and extracting the program and the document class.

The `\A` is to restrict to the start of the file
and the last two lines of the pattern are optional, yet greedy (operator `?`).
This is not the whole truth, but I want to identify root files
when either a class or a program is given.

If I remove the two `?`, the given file is matched
and both, program and class are identified correctly
and show up in their respective named groups.

If I add both `?` as above, then only the second, the class is matched,
or well, at least only the class shows up in the group.
The other group has value `null` indicating no match.
If I use only one `?` then only the other, non-optional part is matched, at least that is what shows up in the groups.

If I understand the theory of regex right,
then `?` is greedy and so both, class and program must be matched
in the version of the pattern above.

This is not the case.
Is this a bug or do I misunderstand something?

Reading my own question again, ...
since the first line of my string matches the second line of my pattern
and the second line of my string matches the third line of my pattern,
I think it is more likely that matching is ok,
but the matched texts don't show up in the correct groups.
This would be an indication of a bug in java's regex engine.
Any other ideas??

Comment: What exactly is the behaviour that you want?

Comment: @anubhava as i said: "If I understand the theory of regex right, then ? is greedy and so both, class and program must be matched in the version of the pattern above."

Comment: "*I do matching with multiline flag.*": As in `Pattern.MULTILINE`? You don't have any `^` or `$` anchors in your regex, so that flag is unnecessary.

Comment: @user2609605, you should add a _tex_, or _latex_, tag for this.

Comment: If you are just trying to avoid matching the empty string, add a `(?<=[\S\s])` at the end of the Rx. `\A(%\s*!\s*T[eE]X[ ]program=(?<programMagic>[^} ]+)\R)?(\\(documentstyle|documentclass)\s*(\[[^]]*\])?\s*\{(?<docClass>[^} ]+)\})?(?<=[\S\s])` https://regex101.com/r/ZACWuy/1 I must say that your top and bottom optional capture groups are misplaced. Meaning they are both optional and group 2 can be matched at the `\A` if group 1 is absent. Group 1 seems to contain a hard coded header `%\s*!\s*T[eE]X` which should not be optional.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to identify root files when either a class or a program is given.

You may use this regex with alternation:

```bash
\A(?:%\s*!\s*T[eE]X program=(?<programMagic>[^} ]+)\R|(?:.*\R)?\\(documentstyle|documentclass)\s*\[[^]]*]\s*\{(?<docClass>[^} ]+)})
```

Note that pretty much all of your regex pattern is used here but we are using it like:

```bash
\A(?:patternLine1\R|(?:\R)?patternLine2)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kUvnDe/1)

Comment: No,first of all is my question why my pattern does not work, 
It was not that I want another pattern. 

Then it shall be possible to have both matches. 
in fact, it is not only about matching of the expression but about matching of the groups.
The pattern I gave always matches, at worst the empty string. But the difference is which groups are matched. 
The groups pull information out of the file.

Comment: I know I said, i want to find out latex root files. this is not a lie but it is not the whole truth.

Comment: I think your pattern is not intuitive and elegant but above all not performant.

Comment: `why my pattern does not work`: It works how it is supposed to work. I think you didn't fully understand the intent of the question I asked below your question. You can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/kUvnDe/2) that both lines are being matched with `?`

Comment: Nono, your pattern does work. I know. I made another point.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> (?&lt;programMagic&gt;[^} ]+)\R)
> ```

This is.. bizarre. I assume something got lost in copy and pasting, and what you *meant* to put there is `(?<programMagic>;[^} ]+)`.

Applying that minor fix, I cannot reproduce your problem. Possibly your attempt to translate this stuff to java failed. Double escaping those backslashes can be a right pain. Here it is:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
"\\A" +
"(%\\s*!\\s*T[eE]X program=(?<programMagic>[^} ]+)\\R)?" +
"(\\\\(documentstyle|documentclass)\\s*(\\[[^]]*\\])?\\s*\\{(?<docClass>[^} ]+)\\})?");

String txt = "% !TEX program=lualatex\n" +
"\\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}";

var m = p.matcher(txt);
System.out.println(m.matches());
System.out.println("G1: '" + m.group("programMagic") + "'");
System.out.println("G2: '" + m.group("docClass") + "'");

String txt = "% !TEX program=lualatex\n" +
"\\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}";

m = p.matcher("% !TEX program=lualatex\n");
System.out.println(m.matches());
System.out.println("G1: '" + m.group("programMagic") + "'");
System.out.println("G2: '" + m.group("docClass") + "'");

m = p.matcher("\\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}");
System.out.println(m.matches());
System.out.println("G1: '" + m.group("programMagic") + "'");
System.out.println("G2: '" + m.group("docClass") + "'");
```

Does as far as I can tell exactly what you wanted:

```
true
G1: 'lualatex'
G2: 'book'
true
G1: 'lualatex'
G2: 'null'
true
G1: 'null'
G2: 'book'
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.. in fact, i made a mistake in transforming the pattern which i actually read in from an xml file. 
Really, regex is a pain with java string literals. I will correct using multi line string literals.

I rethink what went wrong. 

Which java version do you use??

Comment: That was running on jdk21.

Comment: @all sorry for the noise!!! 
I found the problem: After all, I was reading from a file and (shame on me), 
provided the matcher not with the full text at once. 
This is the explanation. 

Sorry for the noise!!!! 

I will in future always try to provide a small example to avoid like this.